# How can I automatically set the window title in konsole (kde) to be my $pwd string?

Tags: title, working-directory, konsole

Here's what I would do to set the title interactively via shell:

```
echo -ne "\033]30;$PWD\007"
```

How can I make the above happen automatically each time I change my working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set konsole's window title to be some string as defined below:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$(basename ${PWD})\007"'
```

or

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]30;$PWD\007"'
```

The title of konsole should change immediately when you run either command.

Found the answer here:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command/

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your shell prompt $PS1, it will be executed after every command (including changing directories). You need to escape the dollar sign in `$PWD` or it will only be executed when you are setting the prompt, instead of every time the prompt is displayed. You can do this by executing the following line:

```
PS1="\033]30;\$PWD\007$PS1"
```

Which should just add it to the beginning of your shell prompt. I would also recommend adding it to your `.bashrc` or profile script so it is done automatically on startup.

Comment: Appreciate the response, but that doesn't stick. It does it once, but not when I cd to different directory.

Comment: Hi Kevin, The solution you provided has a bad side-effect: the shell command line wraps prematurely and things get messed up after that. Took me some time to figure out this change was the reason.